# androidTest error AAPT: error: attribute android:forceQueryable not found

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, android-testing

I get the below error when trying to run androidTest

Error

```
> Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/xx/yy/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":21}}],"original":"/Users/xx/yy/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/AndroidManifest.xml:22: AAPT: error: attribute android:forceQueryable not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/xx/yy/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/AndroidManifest.xml:22: AAPT: error: attribute android:forceQueryable not found.
```

Test file

```
package com.xx.view

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingRegistry
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiSelector
import com.xx.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf
import org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf
import org.junit.*
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

    lateinit var context: Context
    lateinit var app: Application
    lateinit var mainActivity: MainActivity
    lateinit var idlingResource: MainActivityIdlingResource
    private lateinit var myDevice: UiDevice


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        app = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext as Application
        mainActivity = mActivityTestRule.activity

        myDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
        idlingResource = MainActivityIdlingResource(mActivityTestRule.activity.recyclerList, mActivityTestRule.activity.javaClass.simpleName)
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource)
        //mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null)
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource)
    }
}
```

App Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst("META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module")
    }

}

dependencies {
    
    //Test dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0';
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.1-alpha02'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockk_version"

}
```

Comment: Same question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725027/12522931